# Nativescript: Downloading images from URL for offline use

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript JAVASCRIPT application, Upon a sync request, Data is downloaded from a webservice (JSON) and stored in a local Sqlite database on the device. (multiple records, 10-200). this is for use when off-line.

one of the fields in this datasets is the url for an image, each record has its own image. as part of the data-sync i would like to download and save all the images.

any ideas of the best way to go about this?

eg

```
    http.getJSON("https://myURL").then(function(r) {
      for (var i = 0; i< r.length; i++) {
         database.execSQL("INSERT INTO ....);
         /// HERE I WANT TO GET AND SAVE THE IMAGE
      }
    })
```

Comment: You may use SQLite Blob to store the image / write it to documents directory for later use.

Comment: Hi - i,ve decided to go with base64 and store in db :)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a good idea, base64 encoding produces long string like around a million characters for high resolution images. Android has certain issues on character length / memory, your queries may start returning simply null for all the fields post insert. If it's low resolution image within 1 or 2 mb you might be still good with base64 encoding.

Comment: The images are small - 7-9k, the base64 strings are only coming in at 7-10k :)